# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable en python

Tags: python

Se supone que si el espacio se encuentra en **False** significa que está libre y se dice **True** significa que esta ocupado y las funciones corresponden a la verificacion de si un lugar se encuentra libre u ocupado, a la ocupación de un lugar libre y la liberación de un lugar ocupado respectivamente.

````
ocupacion = [[False,False,False],
             [False,False,False],
             [False,False,False]]

puestos = {1:[0,0],2:[0,1],3:[0,2],
           4:[1,0],5:[1,1],6:[1,2],
           7:[2,0],8:[2,1],9:[2,2]  
           }

def validar(puesto, ocupacion):
  fila, columna = puestos[puesto]
  if ocupacion[fila][columna] == False:
    return "Libre"
  else:
    return "Ocupado"

def ocupar(puesto, ocupacion, validacion):
  fila, columna = puestos[puesto]
  if ocupacion[fila][columna] == False:
    ocupacion[fila][columna] = True
    return ocupacion

def liberar(puesto, ocupacion, validacion):
  fila, columna = puestos[puesto]
  if ocupacion[fila][columna] == True:
    ocupacion[fila][columna] = False
    return ocupacion
  else:
    ocupacion=ocupacion


validacion = validar(2,ocupacion) #Ocupar
print(validacion)
ocupacion = ocupar(2,ocupacion,validacion)
print(ocupacion[0][1])


validacion = validar(2,ocupacion) #Intento Ocupar si está lleno
print(validacion)
ocupacion = ocupar(2,ocupacion,validacion)
print(ocupacion[0][1])


validacion = validar(2,ocupacion)#Liberar
print(validacion)
ocupacion = liberar(2,ocupacion,validacion)
print(ocupacion[0][1]) ```
````

Comment: Según tus condicionales, en la función ocupar, si ocupacion[fila][columna] no es igual a True, devuelve None. Luego tratas de aplicar rebanado en el objeto None, que por supuesto no acepta rebanado. Que esperabas que hiciera la función?

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en las funciones ocupar y liberar, ya que no retornabas nada en caso de que una condición no se cumpla.

```
def ocupar(puesto, ocupacion, validacion):
  fila, columna = puestos[puesto]
  if ocupacion[fila][columna] == False:
    ocupacion[fila][columna] = True
    return ocupacion # Como vez solo retorna algo en caso de ser False

def liberar(puesto, ocupacion, validacion):
  fila, columna = puestos[puesto]
  if ocupacion[fila][columna] == True:
    ocupacion[fila][columna] = False
    return ocupacion # Aquí no retornas nada a menos de que sea true,
```

solo lo reasignas
else:
ocupacion=ocupacion

Lo que yo hice para corregirlo es esto y ya funciona normal:

```
def ocupar(puesto, ocupacion, validacion):
    fila, columna = puestos[puesto]
    if ocupacion[fila][columna] == False:
        ocupacion[fila][columna] = True
    return ocupacion # Quítamos la reasignación innesesaria y retornamos algo obligatoriamente.

def liberar(puesto, ocupacion, validacion):
    fila, columna = puestos[puesto]
    if ocupacion[fila][columna] == True:
        ocupacion[fila][columna] = False

    return ocupacion
```